# ggplot2/ggh4x facet_nested: how to rotate a single layer when there is more than one?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am struggling with plotting nice headers in a nested arranged plot where there is more than one facet and one of the colnames is too long. Because `strip.text.x = ggplot2::element_text(size = 9, angle=90)` rotate both facets, the header session became too large.
This is how "sublayer" should be:
[image]

I would like to rotate only the "sublayer" facet and keep the "mainlayer" horizontal so the space would be large there.
And this is how "mainlayer" should be:
[image]

Could anyone help me on how to rotate only one layer?
All the best.

---

This is a toy .tsv data.frame:

```
Sample  value   sublayer    mainlayer   AB  CD
s1  40.55755852 a text  AA1 nana    caca
s2  22.76443406 other text  AA2 nana    dada
s3  33.3715906  here a long text    AA1 nana    dada
s4  22.98811774 a text  AA2 nana    baba
s5  39.75140713 other text  AA1 nana    baba
s6  39.53447467 here a long text    AA2 nana    dada
```

And this is load and plotting code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggh4x)
library(forcats)

data <- read.table("data.txt", sep = "\t", header = T) 

data %>%
  mutate(x = fct_reorder(CD, value, .fun = mean, .desc = TRUE)) %>%
  ggplot(aes_string(x = "Sample", y = "value", fill = "x")) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack", color = "black") + 
  facet_nested(. ~ majorlayer + sublayer, scales = "free", space = "free_x") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), legend.position = "bottom", 
        axis.text.x.bottom = element_blank(),
        strip.text.x = ggplot2::element_text(size = 9, angle=0), 
        legend.title = element_blank()) + xlab("") + ylab("")
```

Comment: this is tricky, you may need to get into `grid` package ! I did something like this sometimes back, but I had to make the facets manually in `grid`, then stick them with the plot. BTW, can't you just use `facet_grid`?

Comment: Thanks, Liman. @chemdork123 brought a solution on this way (using grid).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed you did not have any axis text on the x axis, so rather than going the route of potentially having to use `grid` to display your facets, why not just move the x axis text to the top of the plot and rotate it, and at the same time move the strip text (facet label) outside of the facet?

```
library(scales)

ggplot(df, aes(x=sublayer, y=value)) +
  geom_col(color='black', aes(fill=CD), position=position_dodge(0.5), width=0.5) +
  facet_grid(.~mainlayer) +
  scale_x_discrete(position='top', labels=wrap_format(10)) +
  labs(x=NULL) +
  theme(
    strip.placement = 'outside',
    axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, hjust=0, vjust=0),
    strip.background = element_rect(fill='white'),
    strip.switch.pad.grid = unit(10,'pt')
  )
```

[image]

Note that I'm using `wrap_format()` from `scales` to wrap your "long text" in the axis label.

Comment: This works for this specific plot, but does not generalize to plots that do have an x-axis and still use `facet_nested()`